# Unsupported projection option: numberOfPersons: { description: 1 }

Tags: mongoose

**It can model**

```
const tourSchema = new Schema({
  image: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  numberOfPersons: {
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  },
})

const tourModel = mongoose.model("Tour", tourSchema);
```

**when i use select**

```
const doc = await tourModel.find(
        {},
        {
          image: 1,
          numberOfPersons: {
            description: 1,
          },
        }
      );
```

i get error

> Unsupported projection option: numberOfPersons: { description: 1 }

What is the reason ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation for selecting the field in the JSON object

```js
const doc = await tourModel.find(
  {},
  {
    'image': 1,
    'numberOfPersons.description': 1,
  }
);
```